# Writing a Quicksort with one loop

Tags: java, loops, quicksort

My brother wants me to optimize my code by only having one loop.  I don't see how a Quicksort can only have one loop and work. (He told me to remove the inner loop)

```
public class QuickSort {
public static void Quick(int[] target, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi) {
        return;
      }
    Random numberGenerator = new Random();
    int pivot = numberGenerator.nextInt(hi-lo)+lo;
    int pivotValue = target[pivot];
    target[pivot]=target[hi];
    target[hi]=pivotValue;
    pivot=hi;
    int counter;
    for(counter=lo; counter<pivot ; counter++){
        while(target[counter]>target[pivot]){ 
            if(pivot-counter==1){
                int temp=target[counter];
                target[counter]=target[pivot];
                target[pivot]=temp;
                //return; //possibly the problem
            }
            else{
                int temp1 = target[pivot-1];
                int temp2 = target[pivot];
                target[pivot]=target[counter];
                target[pivot-1]=temp2;
                target[counter]=temp1;
                pivot=pivot-1;
            }
        }
    }
    Quick(target, lo, counter-1);
    Quick(target, counter, hi); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sizeOfArray = 10;
    int numberOfTests = 1000;

    int numFailed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++)
    {
        int[] iNeedSorting = new int[sizeOfArray];
        populateArrayWithRandomNums(iNeedSorting);
        //System.out.printf("Test #%d\n", i);
        //System.out.printf("Original Array: %s\n", intArrayToString(iNeedSorting));
        Quick(iNeedSorting, 0, iNeedSorting.length-1);

        if (!isSorted(iNeedSorting)) {numFailed++;}
        //System.out.printf("New Array: %s\n\n", intArrayToString(iNeedSorting));
    }
    System.out.printf("%d test failed\n\n", numFailed);
}
```

}

Comment: Is your question that you can't see the inner loop? It starts at the line beginning with 'while'.

Comment: @Alex Humphrey - I'm saying I need to remove the inner loop `while` so that Quicksort only runs on 1 loop

Comment: Did `Arrays.sort(...)` not make the cut for some reason?

Comment: Two comments: 1) I wouldn't call minimizing the number of loops an "optimization", in the usual sense of the word. A coding challenge it may be, but as these usually are, its target is arbitrary. 2) you may consider using recursion to eliminate the inner loop.

Comment: @Péter Török - Thank you, in this case, I'll try using do-while case

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort is conceptually two loops: an inner partitioning loop that iterates over the whole array, and an outer division loop usually expressed through recursion. Here, you have the division part done in the classical way, but your partitioning is a little complicated.

Your outer `for` loop moves the counter one step to the left (assuming you write your array from left to right). Your inner `for` loop moves the pivot one step to the right (except in the special case where the counter has almost reached the pivot and you do a final swap). There's nothing that moves the counter back towards the right or the pivot back towards the left. So you're not doing extra work because of the two loops, it's a matter of clarity rather than efficiency.

A common way to write partitioning is to use a single loop with two counters instead of one. One counter is the one you used: everything to the left of it is less than the pivot. The other counter plays a symmetric role: everything to the right of it is greater than the pivot. The loop body does the following:

- if both `target[left_counter]` and `target[right_counter]` are out-of-place, swap them; after this both `target[left_counter]` and `target[right_counter]` are on the desired side of the array, so increment `left_counter` and decrement `right_counter`;
- otherwise: if `target[left_counter]` is on the desired side, increment `left_counter`; if `target[right_counter]` is on the desired side, decrement `right_counter`.

The loop terminates when the counters cross over. It will eventually terminate because at least one of the counters moves at each iteration.

Comment: Guess a typo here "The other counter plays a symmetric role: everything to the right of it is less than the pivot." I think everything to right of right pointer should be 'greater' than the pivot. Correct? Also, I also had the same desire, to write quicksort using only a single loop, but if we use 2 pointers, left and right all implementations show that there is one parent loop and then internal 2 loops one for advancing left pointer and other for advancing the right pointer. That's the question, can't we advance these 2 pointers using only the outer parent loop?

Comment: @SaurabhPatil I fixed the typo, thanks. You can use a single `while` loop for the partitioning step, where you update either the left pointer or the right pointer at each step.

Answer (score 0):

According to the academics (or at least the quicksort algorithm that I studied and I also made a quick check to the data structures and algorithms book), quicksort is about recursion. Partitioning the dataset (which needs a loop) and then recursively sorting the left and right sides of it.